# Create reactjs application Command not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Every time I write create-react-app projectname.
i am facing problem like command not found.

`npx create-react-app`
command not found: create-react-app

Comment: What is your node and npm version? (type node -v and npm -v)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of the app you want to create:

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Also, make sure you have [node installed](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score -1):

`create-react-app` should be installed globally

Run this

```
npm i create-react-app -g
```

Then create your app

```
create-react-app app-name
```

Comment: this is not true for newer versions of node and npm. Nowadays npx comes out of the box with the npm package and facebook warns against installing `create-react-app` globally, as it breaks some package dependencies

Comment: ok, I was not aware of this. Can you share some reference link that verifies this.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app. It does not specify here about the part where. as of 12/19 npm does not support global installs. So you should not install it globally on newer versions of npm.